# On a difference between a class and a set under ZFC theory

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Is any finite class a set under ZFC theory? or are there conditions still required to ensure that? condition like having a mathematical definition in first-order logic for any element of the class.

I am trying to give a mathematical representation of a collection of organisms, and it would be quite nice if it is a set, so I could describe a topology on it (or is it possible to have a concept of topology without the axiomatic set concept?). The other possibility may be working on category theory.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How are you defining 'class'? As the basic objects in $\mathsf{NBG}$? In the sense of the subsets of a fixed model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? As predicates (in the language of set theory) of the form $\varphi(x)$ (up to equivalence over $\mathsf{ZFC}$)? From your context, it sounds like you're using it to describe just informal notion of 'collection' -- unless you've defined what an 'organism' is in set-theoretic terms, you're right that a collection of 'organisms' isn't a set in a strict sense. But it is 'in bijection' with a finite set, so it may as well be.

Comment: ...(con't) If you fixed a way to associate an organism with a set (or perhaps just a natural number), then reasoning about the 'class of all organisms' would be the same as reasoning about the 'set of all IDs of organisms'.

Comment: Hi, @Hayden. I am defining it as predicates the form φ(x). If a finite collection of organisms (e.g., ants) is "in bijection" with a finite set (let's say a finite index set), then can I state that that collection is a set?

Comment: @JohnMedina-Diaz Yes, any finite class is a set. Not sure what you're doing exactly, but why not just make it part of the formalization to identify the organisms with the natural numbers in the first place? What else would you identify them with? (Also not sure why such attention to set theoretical detail is warranted in this context.)

Comment: Hi, @spaceisdarkgreen. So in ZFC, any finite class is a set (although a class seems to be informally defined there)? I cannot formalize an organism $\mathcal{O}$  as a natural number, seemingly, because $\mathcal{O}$ has an inner structure (i.e., $\mathcal{O}$ will be a collection with some meaningful structure or property similar like the property of an *abstract simplicial complex*). What is a mathematical object then? I'm not quite sure for now how well it could work the "formal" approach you've mentioned in your last comment ($A=\{(0,0),..., (0, n-1)\}$)

Comment: What happened to your other comments?

Comment: @JohnMedina-Diaz Deleted them. Not cause anything was wrong with them per se, but just didn't want to engage in a long rant that made too many assumptions about what you were doing. Sorry about this. Yes, in ZFC a class is informal, but in a theory with formalized classes like NBG or MK, a finite class will be a set as well. (And then "any finite class is a set" can be stated and proven as a statement, rather than a scheme.) If your organisms are complicated mathematical objects in their own right, then would think formalizing *those* as sets would be the primary concern.

Comment: See section 7 of the following (2008) arxiv-paper by M. A. Shulman <https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279>

Comment: ...(con't) The entire arxiv-paper may be worth reading to understand different ways to embed category theory within set theory (which at the moment does not have consensus and I don't see consensus developing anytime soon).